# Редирект из выбранного select при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, localstorage

при заходе на главную страницу пользователю предлагается выбрать его город.
Сейчас там стоит список из трех городов (будет больше)при выборе которого переадресовывается сразу на нужную категорию города.

```
   <select onchange="location.href=this.value" size="1" name="custom1">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" >Выберите город</option>
    <option value="/nv86/">Нижневартовск</option>
    <option value="/megion/" >Мегион</option>
    <option value="/surgut/" >Сургут</option>
```

При заходе на главную страницу снова, он запоминает выбранный ранее город (через куки) (выбранный ранее селект) например Мегион, выбирает его снова автоматом, но редирект происходит только при изменении города (onchange). Приходится снова выбирать свой город, хоть ты его и видишь.

Подскажите, как вынести функцию переадресации(редиректа) отдельной кнопкой или чтоб автоматически переадресовывалось в выбранный ранее город (выбранный ранее город он запоминает нормально)
т.е. чтоб у списка была кнопка "Подвердите что это ваш город" 
или сразу редиректился "а ну вы уже выбирали, вот вам в /megion/ переадресация"
[image: Genius]

Comment: Сделайте проверку на куки, и если они есть переадресовывайте

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { 
     $('select[name="custom1"]').change(function() { 
         if(getCookie('color') != '0') { 
             setCookie('color', $(this).val(), 365); 
         }; 
     }); 
     if(getCookie('color')) { 
         $('select[name="custom1"]').val(getCookie('color')).find('option[value="' + getCookie('color') + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected'); 
     }; 
});

Comment: color это название кука, custom1 название поля. Как я понял при загрузке если что-то выбрано (не является 0), то он устанавливает выбор поля custom1 на то что запомнило(запоминает и само выбирает нормально)
но вот как заместо просто выбора тогда переадресацию на значение поля сделать :(  window.location.href = "здесь значение поля"  вот как и куда вставить, я не бум бум. 
Но всё равно спасибо, что хоть пояснили, что проблема решаема. Буду искать решение